# How to dcode the video whose encoding format starts with \x?

Tags: video, decode

I want to use python to download video from a website.But when I successfully download it,I can't play it with the media palyer or others players.So I check the encoding format and I found \x in every byte.[The image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR6ZS.png) So how can I decode this format?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: _"I can't play it with the media player"_ Download a **hex editor** for your OS and check file bytes with that one. In Python I think `\xFF` signifies a byte values like to `0xFF` or `255` as decimal. There is no `x` in bytes, only values going from `0...9` and `A...F`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Mybe I need learn more thing to solve this problem.